# Maven: Filtering persistence.xml

Tags: maven, filtering, war

In our Peoject, the `persistence.xml` is located in the relative directory

`/src/main/resources/META-INF`,

and without giving any additional instructions in the pom in the file is copied to

`/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF`

during the Maven build process. This is fine so far as hibernate is able to pick the configuration file from there. But now we wanted to centralize some configuration values and therefore use the `maven-war-plugin` to replace the respictive wildcards in the `persistence.xml`

The filtering itself is performed for various other files and working as expected. For the `persistence.xml` however it seems to fail for various reasons:

When just adding the `persistence.xml` to the `webResources`:

```
<resource>
    <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/META-INF/</directory>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
    <includes>
        <include>persistence.xml</include>
    </includes>
</resource>
```

The file is filtered properly, but ofc. thrown into the root of the outputdirectory, where hibernate is not looking for it.

When trying to provide the desired target-folder:

```
<resource>
    <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/META-INF/</directory>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
    <includes>
        <include>persistence.xml</include>
    </includes>
    <targetPath>WEB-INF/classes/META-INF</targetPath>
</resource>
```

the file is not filtered properly. **I assume that filtering would actually work, but since the file has already been copied there, maven refuses to override the file still containing wildcards**

Any ideas how to make this work without reinventing the wheel?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured out the solution. Just posting, in case anybody stumbles over the same issue:

The filtering listed above was wrapped in `<webResources>` tags, cause it's actually about processing the webapp-content.

So, in a nutshell I told maven to deploy every **resource** without touching it, and when deploying **webresources** try to process a **resource** and deploy it to a **resource-folder** - which already has happened unprocessed.

Comment: Too uninformative, especially when dealing with Maven.

Answer (score 2):

Here you have a snippet of XML code that works for me:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.3</version>
  <configuration>
    <webResources>                         
      <resource>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <directory>src/main/resources/META-INF</directory>                            
        <includes>
          <include>**/persistence.xml</include>
        </includes>
        <targetPath>WEB-INF/classes/META-INF</targetPath>
      </resource>               
    </webResources>  
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks Paco, that pointed me to the right direction. I used `<resources>` tag instead of `<webResources>` and had to use only `META-INF` as targetPath, but otherwise it worked great.